# Most elegant way to .format() formatted string with arbitrary length list in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Recently I was rewriting code in which a string variable was assigned in following way:

```
mylist = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
somestring = '%6.3f' * len(mylist) % tuple(mylist)

In [7]: somestring

Out[7]: ' 1.000 2.000 3.000'
```

I would like to figure out how to do same using the `.format()` method.
I ended up with following:

```
somestring = ''.join('{:6.3f} ' for i in mylist).format(*mylist)
In [16]: somestring

Out[16]: ' 1.000  2.000  3.000 '
```

Is there any way to do it "better"? (also in one line?)

Comment: Format floats in the loop: `''.join(format(x, '6.3f') for x in mylist)`

Comment: The exact same thing using `.format()` would be: `('{:6.3f}' * len(mylist)).format(*mylist)`. But that's not really elegant.

Comment: "Better"? That seems very subjective.

Comment: @ppperry We could always define "Better" as most pythonic.  Assuming the quotes around "Better" isn't supposed to make the question ironic or sarcastic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you can use `%` on the multiplied string, you can use `.format()` on the multiplied string.  You need to use parentheses to keep it contained, though:

```
somestring = ('{:6.3f}' * len(mylist)).format(*mylist)
```